# how to convert list or mutablelist into dataset inscala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, backend

If I convert mutableList into Dataset like this:

```
Val list = mutableList()
Val dataset = list.toDS()
```

An error occurs:

> 21/09/29 16:05:25 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage
> 3.0 (TID 3) java.lang.NullPointerException
> at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits.localSeqToDatasetHolder(SQLImplicits.scala:231)
> at main.ylcx.mallRec.recommend$.$anonfun$main$6(recommend.scala:87)
> at main.ylcx.mallRec.recommend$.$anonfun$main$6$adapted(recommend.scala:58)
> at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
> at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
> at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreach$2(RDD.scala:1012)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreach$2$adapted(RDD.scala:1012)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2236)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
> at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
> at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Is there any other way to do it? Or how to solve this error?

Comment: What version of spark are you using ? What is the parametrized type of MutableList (type of elements of your mutable list) ? On Spark 3.1, I'm not able to get your error. With your code I get a compilation error, and if I correct this compilation error by adding type to list constructor as follow `val list = MutableList[String]()` I get no error and I'm able to create an empty `dataset` dataset.

Comment: @VincentDoba thanks for your reply. I’m using scala 3.1.2. And yes. It is fine while runing. But if I submit jar into spark cluster, this error occurs everytime. Parametrized type is Rating class in ALS model.